Problems to configure the BIOS to boot the computer from an Ubuntu LiveUSB
When I turn on the computer I get this message:
Could not create SbatLevelRT: Volume Full
Could not create MokListTrustedRT: Volume Full
Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state ( ) failed: Volume Full
And then the computer shuts down.
To solve it I have tried the following:

I created an Ubuntu LiveUSB.
I have configured the BIOS to force boot from LiveUSB with these changes:


Disable “Secure Boot”.
Boot mode select : I have changed the “UEFI” option to “LEGACY”.
FIXED BOOT ORDER PRIORITIES. Boot Option #1: I changed the option “NVME:Ubuntu...” to “USB Device”.
But it doesn't work either. It doesn't boot from USB, the same error message from the beginning appears on the screen again.
Am I configuring the BIOS correctly?
I have a computer with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and BIOS Core Version 5.16; Compliancy UEFI 2.7; PI 1.6; version 2.20.1275. CPU Model: AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon Graphics.
Can anyone help me? It is urgent. Thanks. Regards.


Did your machine ever boot? Encryption used? Dual Boot? Did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO? How did you create the boot USB (the ISO boot UEFI and legacy, but some tools allow selecting one way)?  Why did you select legacy mode in UEFI setings? The settings boot order may be dual level 1)USB CD, USB hdd, hdd, net,...) and 2)UEFI hard disks (which may or may not include the USB hdd). Add requested info to your original posting, comments are for us to ask questions,...

Do not turn on Legacy/CSM/BIOS boot. You want UEFI with gpt partitioning unless system over 10 years old. Issues with MOK - machine owner key are related to UEFI Secure boot. Ubuntu will boot with Secure boot on, but if proprietary drivers required for Video or Wi-Fi drivers (like nVidia) then user must create the MOK.

Many thanks, ubfan1 and oldfred, for your replies!
